# Is there anything that would prevent a wealthy farmer from having his meat come from regenerating animals?

Tags: dnd-5e

Note: I'm currently not actively playing any RPGs, this is just something I came up with and wanted to know if it's actually feasible within the rules. If this idea strikes you as interesting, feel free to use it in your own campaign.

So the idea I had was as follows: a wealthy farmer who provides meat for most of a major city (think the size of Baldur's Gate or Neverwinter in their prime) has a suspiciously small farm for the amount of meat he supplies. Turns out that somehow, the farmer has managed to give all of his animals a passive Regeneration effect somehow, similar to the Ring of Regeneration. He simply cuts off the meat and/or organs he needs and then gives the animal time to regenerate, then repeats the process.

So the questions I have about this subject:

1. Would this be allowed through either RAW or a minimal application of house rules? I'm wondering specifically about:

   - Can Regeneration do this?
   - What possible ways are there for him to give the animals the effect? I assume a Ring of Regeneration wouldn't work if it's not on a finger.
   - Would the meat be fit for consumption?
2. Less related to 5e itself, but would this be economically feasible?

Comment: Related: http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0326.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RAW is irrelevant for all of this.

The rules could never state the exact process required for every possible magical effect a DM may wish to invent. There is not going to be a rule for giving sheep regeneration any more than there could be a specific rule for a group of cultists inventing a ritual that releases Tiamat from Her hellish prison!

A DM has to be free to invent this stuff for the purposes of his own campaign.

As to whether regeneration could do this (putting aside the fact that a DM could always create whatever effect he wanted): the Ring of Regeneration specifically states it even regrows lost body parts over time, so if your hypothetical farm animal regenerated the same way then, yes, you could chop off a leg and wait for it to grow back.

The other questions of how he could do this and whether the meat would be fit for consumption falls under DM fiat.

How this would be treated alignment-wise is going be a subject of debate. Probably a can of worms to bring that up here.

Economical feasibility? Again - this is going to depend too much on your setting and how the effect is granted. If it costs 10,000gp to create one regenerating cow (not an unfair amount for an incredibly powerful effect) then its doubtful a farmer could afford it in the first place. A single farmer with this secret probably wouldn't upset the balance too much - though if anyone found out about it he would probably be the target of every cattle rustler in a 100 miles!

Answer (score 1):

### Would this work?

yes. the ring of Regeneration gives back severed limbs after 1d6+1 days. he could have the ring pierced through the ears of the animals which is a common practice in cattle anyway. One thing to consider is if there are enough rings in the world to make this happen or if there are people able to make them on command.

I guess the meat would not be the best quality, just look at the real world fast meaty growing animals. but RAW it never says anything about it not being able to eat the regenerated meat.

### Would you make bank?

After the huge amount of rings that would need to be bought? yes.

The rings are very rare quality so that would cost you a pretty penny (5000-50000 gold per ring for 5e). but after the initial investment you start to earn money pretty fast compared to normal meat farms. it would early depend in the setting, the price of the rings and the price of the meat. but keep it up long enough and you would probably make some good money.

Comment: Keep it going long enough and someone from the thieves guild will come along as well.